# Mapping columns from one dataframe to another to create a new column with missing values

Tags: python, pandas

My main df has a column named product_code I want to map it with another df1 with a product_code column in order to add product_type from df1 into df.
My problem is that df.product_code has more values than df1.product_code.

df :

`` `       product_code customer_code market_code  order_date  sales_qty ``  
`0           Prod001        Cus001     Mark001  2017-10-10        100`
`1           Prod013        Cus001     Mark001  2017-10-10        240`
`2           Prod016        Cus001     Mark001  2018-06-28        187`
`3           Prod020        Cus001     Mark001  2017-10-10        140`
`4           Prod020        Cus001     Mark001  2017-10-25         47`
`...             ...           ...         ...         ...        ...`
`149996      Prod301        Cus034     Mark011  2017-12-22          1`
`149997      Prod301        Cus034     Mark011  2018-11-05          1`
`149998      Prod301        Cus034     Mark011  2019-09-05          1`
`149999      Prod302        Cus034     Mark011  2017-12-22          1`
`150000      Prod302        Cus034     Mark011  2019-09-05          1`

df1 :

```
 product_code    product_type
0        Prod001     Own Brand\n
1        Prod002     Own Brand\n
2        Prod003     Own Brand\n
3        Prod004     Own Brand\n
4        Prod005     Own Brand\n
..           ...             ...
274      Prod275     Own Brand\n
275      Prod276     Own Brand\n
276      Prod277     Own Brand\n
277      Prod278  Distribution\n
278      Prod279  Distribution\n
```

So far I have been lucky and only had to merge columns with matching values using this formula :

`df2 = (df.merge(df1, left_on='product_code', right_on='product_code')           .reindex(columns=['product_code', 'customer_code', 'market_code', 'order_date','sales_qty', 'sales_amount', 'currency','markets_name','zone','customer_name','product_type']))`

I know I will have NaN values in df2.product_type but I need to map it anyway. Any advice?

Comment: Can you just add `how='left'` to your merge?

Comment: It gives me the same error KeyError: 'product_code'

Comment: Are you sure there's no leading/trailing spaces for one of the columns? Try `print(df.columns)` and `print(df2.columns)` to double check that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a left merge. This will take all of the values from `df` and import the matching values from `df1`. Also to simplify your code a bit you can use the `on` parameter (Note: this only works if both dataframes have a column with the same name) instead of the `left_on` and `right_on`.

```
df2 = df.merge(df1, how='left', on='product_code')
```

Here is the full documentation for the `pandas.DataFrame.merge()` function it will give you all of the available parameters with examples: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html